# How do i show all Listpicker items in current page in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

I use a Listpicker in a Listbox inside a ScrollViewer. If the number of items in the Listpicker is 3 (or less than 3), the Listpicker opens as a ComboBox in the current page. But if the number of items is more than 3, it opens in another page, not as a ComboBox. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set number of items that as displayed on an other page by setting `ItemCountThreshold` property of ListPicker. Eg. setting ItemCountThreshold=3 will force ListPicker to show items on new page when there are more then 3 items available to select.

More info about ListPicker properties can be fount eg. here: [ListPicker for WP7 in depth](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)

Comment: This appears to be no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

ListPicker is a new control in the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone. It is for user's to choose another item like Combobox but ListPicker has more features than a Combobox. When you have little item about 1->4 it'll show data as a Combobox and if more item Listpicker will show data as a ListBox.

Refer this **[Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f397b9/using-listpicker-in-windows-phone-7/)** to get perfect idea.

Answer (score 0):

Read [**this article**](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth) and certainly pay attention to the "ItemCountThreshold" property.

> *ItemCountThreshold is a dependency property of type int. It specifies the maximum number of items that will be displayed in Expanded mode. By default, lists with five or fewer items expand in-place while lists with more items switch to a full-screen selection interface. It can also be set to 0 to switch Full mode or a very large number to switch Expanded mode.*

Answer (score 0):

While the toolkit team advised to adhere to the restriction, there are workarounds for this issue. A value can be set via code and also via a binding.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ItemCountThreshold="{Binding Hugo,FallbackValue=10}">(...)
<!-- Hugo is a bogus binding that does not really exist -->
```

See my detailed [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271482/154900).