# ListPicker in windows phone with localization strings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I'm using Toolkit ListPicker in my Windows Phone 8 project and have begun localising it. I've run into a problem because i can't figure out how to do this with a ListPicker.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstClubsPick" 
                    FontSize="30" 
                    Grid.Column="1"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding KolleSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
                    ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" >

<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.chooseClub, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
<sys:String>Choose</sys:String>
<sys:String>D1</sys:String>
<sys:String>D2</sys:String>
<sys:String>D3</sys:String>
<sys:String>D4</sys:String>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ClubClicked">
            <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=lstPivot,Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"></cal:Parameter>
            <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=lstClubsPick,Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"></cal:Parameter>
        </cal:ActionMessage>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So the problem I'm facing is that i don't know how to get `<sys:String>Choose</sys:String>` to look for a string in my AppResources.resx. I've tried this:

```
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.chooseClub, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
```

instead of the `<sys:string>` but that makes my app crash. I've searched google and that was the only possible solution i could find. Anyone able to help me? Would be much appreciated.

EDIT 1: So I've updated my code with the solution from andreask but my ListPicker is not responding to the string i add in my viewModel.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _data;

public ObservableCollection<string> Data
{
    get
    {
        return _data;
    }
    set { 
        _data = value; 
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Data); 
    }
}

Data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Data.Add("Test");

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstClubsPick" FontSize="30" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectedIndex="{Binding KolleSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly">
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 2: Thanks a lot for your answers you definitely pointed me in the right direction. I found a solution to my problem i binded my Pivot view's ItemsSource and from that i could in me view model add an `ObservableCollection<string>` then i could run this code again from my view model `LstItems[PivotSelectedIndex].Data = new ObservableCollection<string>(items);` where `items` is an string array. So in my String array i could make a string using the app resource with `AppResources.YourResourceName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the items in code, In XAML have your normal ListPicker like this.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstClubsPick" 
                    FontSize="30" 
                    Grid.Column="1"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                   
                    CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding KolleSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" />
```

Then in the C# code create a List and add the localized strings to it like this. And set the list as the ItemsSource of the ListPicker.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add(AppResources.OptionOne);
    items.Add(AppResources.OptionTwo);
    items.Add(AppResources.OptionThree);
    items.Add(AppResources.OptionFour);
    items.Add(AppResources.OptionFive);

    lstClubsPick.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

you should be good to go. Hope it helps

Comment: Can't find lstClubsPick as far as i can see it's because it's inside a  DataTemplate.

Comment: I don't understand, is your ListPicker in side a DataTemplate? Coz, if it is not, the you should definitely be able to find it. Can you update the question with more all at least the XAML inside the ContentPanel Grid so i can get a clear view. Coz the code i gave you is tested and works..

Comment: I've edited my question with a solution that worked. Thanks for your help pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a localization issue, but a problem with the `ListPicker` itself. I know by experience that setting `ExpansionMode` to `FullScreen` doesn't work when specifying the list items in XAML. Try removing the `ExpansionMode` property from the `ListPicker` declaration, does it work now?

If yes, I'm afraid the only option you've got is to declare the list of items in your viewmodel, e.g. as `ObservableCollection<string>`, and bind it like:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ...
```

In this case, `ExpansionMode="FullScreen"` works like a charm, don't ask me why...

If you really want to stick with the list of items declared in XAML code, you'll have to get rid of the `ExpansionMode` property somehow. In the past you could have used the `ItemCountThreshold` property: This one controls whether the picker opens in full screen mode (if it contains more items than specified as `ItemCountThreshold`) or not - set it to 0 to force full screen mode. Unfortunately, this property is not supported any more in current Toolkit versions, and the workarounds discussed in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313291/windows-phone-7-1-listpicker-easy-way-to-go-full-mode/13271482#13271482) don't work for me either.

Comment: Setting the items from codebehind as @KasunKV suggested might also be an alternative solution, depending on whether you like the list of items better in viewmodel code or in codebehind...

Comment: removing ExpansionMode did not work. It still crashes

Comment: did u set the list in C#? does it still crash even after that?

Comment: just to verify if it's a localization problem: does it work when replacing all bindings to LocalizedResources with hardcoded string values?

Comment: It works(and have always worked) when i just use static <sys:string>. The problem gets created when i try to localise it. But i NEED it localised because this is a really big app and to code projects is really not a option when i got 30k lines of code.

Comment: KasunKV if you mean like in your answer then no because i cant find my list, because of it being inside a datatemplate(Haven't been able to fix this yet)

Answer (score 0):

try this..there are two ways..u can do it only using xaml like following code..

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listStatic" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top"                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FullModeHeader="Choose the Mode">
                    <system:String>abc</system:String>
                    <system:String>abc</system:String>
                    <system:String>abc</system:String>
                    <system:String>abc</system:String>
                    <system:String>abc</system:String>
                    <system:String>abc</system:String>
  </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

or you can use both xaml and c# like the following..
add this to your .cs file..

```
 private List<string> SetData()
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data.Add("abc");
            data.Add("abc");
            data.Add("abc");
            data.Add("abc");
            data.Add("abc");
            data.Add("abc");
            data.Add("abc");


            return data;            
        }
```

Add this to main method..

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listDynamic.ItemsSource = SetData();

        }
```

then add the following to the xaml file..

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listDynamic" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FullModeHeader="Choose the Mode">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="6,12,6,12">
                                <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="24" Width="24" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

this works great..hope this will help you..

Comment: I've edited my question with a solution that worked. Thanks for your help pointing me in the right direction.